# GROUP BY of unique users' contributions returns higher totals than expected

Tags: sql

Using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) I'm trying to figure out who the top ten answerers on Stack Overflow are. This is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 COUNT (PostTypeId) postcount, OwnerUserId
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = '2' AND OwnerUserId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY OwnerUserId
ORDER BY postcount DESC
```

And, these are my results:

```
postcount OwnerUserId 
--------- ----------- 
23628     22656       
17505     29407       
12978     157882      
10863     34397       
10598     23354       
10560     17034       
9341      20862       
8600      115145      
7394      57695       
7073      1583
```

The problem is: User 22656 is [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), and his [profile says he has 23,702 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=answers).

I checked the others: [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) is User 29407. His profile indicates he has [17,525 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov?tab=answers), not merely 17,505. The others are all similarly skewed.

Why am I getting wrong totals in `postcount`? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are seeing more answers on Jon's profile because you have a diamond and are seeing his deleted answers.

I see "23,702 Answers" which is closer to the value reported by your query.

The rest of the discrepancy is down to the fact that the data explorer isn't updated on a minute by minute basis so will always report lower totals (assuming people are adding more content of course).